# How can I use one CSS module and adding just another style to it without rewriting the code?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles

I wanna style invalid form to my element in react I have the code like this:

```
<div className={props.invalid ? styles.invalid : styles.main } >
```

but I have to rewrite all the styling codes in main for invalid too and just for invalid add red color border to it.

Comment: `className={`${styles.main} ${props.invalid ? styles.invalid : ''}`}` this way you have the `main` class name and `invalid` if `props.invalid` is `truthy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to style the div in inline style attribute like this:

```
<div styele={props.invalid ? {border-color: 'red'}} />
```

Comment: How can I use it for hover?